# Score values of GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

I'm new to machine learning and in the books and documentation I read there is always a score value between 0 and 1, which represent an accuracy between 0% and 100%.

In my own machine learning code in scikit-learn I get score values between `-750.880810` and `5154.771036`, which confuses me.

```
>>> pipe = Pipeline([("scaler", MinMaxScaler()), ("svr", SVR())])
>>> param_grid = {'svr__C':[0.1, 1, 5], 
              'svr__epsilon':[0.001, 0.01]}
>>> grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, 
                    param_grid=param_grid,
                    cv=GroupKFold(n_splits=24)
                   )
>>> grid.fit(X, y, groups)
GridSearchCV(cv=GroupKFold(n_splits=24), error_score=nan,
         estimator=Pipeline(memory=None,
                            steps=[('scaler',
                                    MinMaxScaler(copy=True,
                                                 feature_range=(0, 1))),
                                   ('svr',
                                    SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0,
                                        degree=3, epsilon=0.1,
                                        gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
                                        max_iter=-1, shrinking=True,
                                        tol=0.001, verbose=False))],
                            verbose=False),
         iid='deprecated', n_jobs=None,
         param_grid={'svr__C': [0.1, 1, 5], 'svr__epsilon': [0.001, 0.01]},
         pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score=False,
         scoring=None, verbose=0)

>>> grid.best_score_
-750.880810
```

Could someone please explain that to me?

***Edit:***

My input data is a measurement of an engine.

I have 12 different failures of the engine and every failure is measured twice => 12x2 = 24 different groups (I will also try 12 groups). Every group consist of:

- X data: 13 different features (temperature, pressure, electric voltage etc.) with 1200 samples per group
- y data: 1 feature (pressure) with 1200 samples per group

Comment: can you create some reproducible example? Also please add the reason for GroupKfold with `n_splits=24`.

Comment: why pressure is present in both input and output variable?

Comment: Sorry for misconception, these are two different pressures. For the sake of clarity: the output variable is not present in the input data.

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy is the usual scoring method for classification problem. For a regression problem, it is R square value.

For `scoring` param in `GridSearchCV`,

> If None, the estimator's score method is used.

For SVR, the default scoring value comes from `RegressorMixin`, which is `R^2`.

Documentation:

> Return the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.
>
> The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual
>           sum of squares ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the total
>           sum of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum().
>
> The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the
>           model can be arbitrarily worse).
>
> A constant model that always
>           predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features,
>           would get a R^2 score of 0.0.

Hence, it sounds wired when you very large/small value as R^2.

A toy example, to understand the scoring output.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, GroupKFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
X, y = datasets.make_regression()
groups = np.random.randint(0, 10, len(X))

pipe = Pipeline([("scaler", MinMaxScaler()), ("svr", svm.SVR())])

parameters = {'svr__C': [ 0.1, 1, 5, 100], 'svr__epsilon': [0.001, 0.1]}
svr = svm.SVR()
clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, cv=GroupKFold(n_splits=2))
clf.fit(X, y, groups)

print(clf.best_score_)
# 0.1239707770092825
```

I would recommend trying with different `cv` and investigate the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I have added more information on my input data. It would be great if you could give me an advice how to handle this kind of data (which cv Method and how many splits)